# match_parent doesn't fill the desired result

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: only white portion is taken and that too after taking match_parent]

I've been trying to add this layout. Everything works fine. I want the second `EditText` to take all the rest height of the layout. I've made this `EditText` as `match_parent` but it can't take all the space,.
can somebody tell me the problem I'm having ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#fff"
              android:id="@+id/createxml_layout_id">

    <EditText
              android:id="@+id/createxml_title_id"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:scrollHorizontally="true"
              android:hint="Title"
              android:textAlignment="center"
              android:textColor="#000"
              android:textAllCaps="true"
              android:textSize="20sp"
              android:maxLength="20"
              android:autoText="false"
              android:inputType="textPersonName"
              android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

  <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="CONTENT HERE"
            android:id="@+id/createxml_content_id"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" >

   </android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>

   <!--</LinearLayout>-->

   </LinearLayout>

   </ScrollView>
```

Comment: 1) don't use fill_parent. Use match_parent. They are the same but fill is old 2) I believe a scrollview's direct child should have wrap_content as height

Comment: Try adding `android:singleLine="false"` to the EditText.

Comment: @TimCastelijns tried both . didn't work.

Comment: @Vucko tried it but no change is done in the preview .

Comment: Why do you need a scrollView anyway if you want to fill the page?

Comment: @Vucko i'm using this layout as a fragment in my main_avtivity . I'm providing editable field for the users to write things and if the content size becomes larger than the screen it should scroll up and down .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use android:fillViewport="true" in your scroll view it will fill up the screen.And in your xml you set weight on edit-text but doesn't set weight sum on parent layout.Set weight-sum on linear layout.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:id="@+id/createxml_layout_id">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/createxml_title_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:hint="Title"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:maxLength="20"
            android:autoText="false"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="CONTENT HERE"
            android:id="@+id/createxml_content_id"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" >

        </android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>

        <!--</LinearLayout>-->

      </LinearLayout>

     </ScrollView>
```

Comment: it worked but i'm still having  a problem . my FAB is being scrolled down with the layout scrool . i need to make it static even if the layout scrolls up or down .

Comment: put the scroll-view inside a relative layout and make your FAB to direct child of relative layout and set your FAB where you want..@AbhishekKumar

Comment: One more thing if you can do , whenever i click the edit text in my phone it opens a keyboard ( thats fine ) but it also comes with a underline on the edittext . i wanna get rid of it .

Comment: Put these two lines in your style folder inside the theme you use <item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@android:color/transparent</item>

Comment: in my second edittext....content is being written from the middle of the vertical editspace...how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">


<LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/createxml_layout_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/createxml_title_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:hint="Title"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/createxml_content_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:hint="CONTENT HERE"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        app:fabSize="mini">

    </android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>

    <!--</LinearLayout>-->

</LinearLayout>
```

You need to use the attribute `android:fillViewport="true"`. If the value is set true it causes child to expand to the height of scroll view if it is required. If the child is taller than `Scroll View` then in that case it has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : It will help to make FAB static even if the layout scrolls up or down .

```
  <LinearLayout
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
      android:id="@+id/scrollView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/createxml_layout_id"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="#fff"
      android:orientation="vertical">

  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/createxml_title_id"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:autoText="false"
      android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
      android:hint="Title"
      android:inputType="textPersonName"
      android:maxLength="20"
      android:scrollHorizontally="true"
      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:textAllCaps="true"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
      android:textColor="#000"
      android:textSize="20sp" />

  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/createxml_content_id"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="10"
      android:hint="CONTENT HERE"
      android:textSize="14sp" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

 <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/fab_frame_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@color/white_overlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
      android:id="@+id/fab"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
      android:layout_margin="10dp"
      android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
      app:fabSize="mini"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where to close the scrollvieww?